# How can I install Python Pydap util module (pydap.util)

Tags: python, installation, opendap

#### What i installed

I installed Pydap on my Ubuntu using:

```
sudo pip install Pydap
```

If I understand properly output of the `pip search pydap` command, I have all Pydap modules installed properly.

But to be 100% sure I also typed:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dap
```

#### No module

However as I can see there's no util path:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydap/util
```

so I am **unable** to import util module (`import pydap.util`) to execute following code:

```
from pydap.util.urs import install_basic_client

install_basic_client()

from pydap.client import open_url
dataset = open_url('https://goldsmr4.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/MERRA2/M2T1NXSLV.5.12.4/2016/06/MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20160601.nc4')
```

(code copied from https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/EL/How+To+Access+Data+With+PyDAP)

It seems that:

```
apt-file find urs.py
```

is not returning any package name to install

### Note

At https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/EL/How+To+Access+Data+With+PyDAP
there's sample 'AUTH MODULE CODE' for those who have no util module installed, but it does not work for me - there's a problem with following line:

```
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', pydap.lib.USER_AGENT)]
```

because pydap.lib has **no** USER_AGENT defined:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'USER_AGENT'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a heads up that I am going to answer the question that I think you are *actually* asking rather than the question that you asked :)

The real question is: "How do I access NASA Earth data that is behind an auth wall?"

Unfortunately the NASA documentation that you are referencing is a bit out of date. There were two different proposals for modification to the Pydap client for allowing authentication to NASA/URS services. A different proposal won out in the end, rather than the one that this NASA wiki is based from.

So the answer to *your* question: "How do I install Pydap.util?", is that you can't, because that was an internal module that has been removed in the most recent version (3.2).

However, it should be possible to access the earth data with a stock install of the most recent version of Pydap. It's now a [supported feature](https://github.com/pydap/pydap/issues/19) and its usage is [described in the documentation](http://www.pydap.org/en/latest/client.html#urs-nasa-earthdata).

You should be able to do so with a few simple lines:

```
from pydap.client import open_url
from pydap.cas.urs import setup_session
session = setup_session("your_username", "your_pw")
dataset = open_url('http://server.example.com/path/to/dataset', session=session)
```

Comment: After installation of additional packages ('numpy singledispatch Webob Jinja2 docopt gunicorn six mechanicalsoup') I'm able to import  'open_url' and 'setup_session', but it seems that I received and error when executing line with setup_session (probably, because I'm behind the proxy (ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='urs.earthdata.nasa.gov', port=443)).

Comment: After running my script on different computer, I'm receiving following error message: Unable to parse token: <!DOCTYPE.  Is it possible to see full response, so that maybe I will have idea what has been returned?